# Calling contracts inside for() loop

Tags: javascript, truffle-contract

I have `.js` file, where the contract has to call five times by passing `rand` as parameter. But `rand` has been overwritten and only the fifth random value is passed to the contract five times:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    var rand =Math.random();
    contractt.deployed().then(function(instance){
    var instancee =instance;
         return instancee.add(rand,{from:wallet,gas:4000000});
        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log('result='+result);
        }) 
   })
}
```

I tried using `setTimeout()` as below:

```
 for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    setTimeout(()=>{
    var rand =Math.random();
    contractt.deployed().then(function(instance){
    var instancee =instance;
         return instancee.add(rand,{from:wallet,gas:4000000});
        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log('result='+result);
        }) 
   })
  },1000);
}
```

However, I still obtain the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really an Ethereum question..

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

For your concrete case, you could do this:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    contractt.deployed().then(function(instance){
        var instancee = instance;
        return instancee.add(Math.random(), {from:wallet,gas:4000000});
    }).then(function(result) {
        console.log('result='+result);
    })
}
```